# Issue aligning icon fonts at center

Tags: html, css, fonts

I´m trying to aling my arrows icon fonts in the center of icon font backgrond.

But its not working. Because for that I need to give margins to my icon font arrow but this icon font have the background, so What I do to my icon font I do to my background...

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem?

**My jsfiddle with the problem illustrated:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mibb/tF4L5/

**My Html:**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <div class="unslider-arrow prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
        <div class="unslider-arrow next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
```

My css:

```
.unslider-arrow 
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}

.prev 
{
    top:95px;
    left:0px;
}

{
    top:95px;
    right:0px;
}

.prev >i{color:#000; font-size:1.5em; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); width:40px; height:40px;}
.next >i{color:#000; font-size:1.5em; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);width:40px; height:40px; }
.prev >i:hover{color:#ccc; cursor:pointer;}
.next >i:hover{color:#ccc;cursor:pointer; }
.next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `line-height: 40px;` and `text-align: center;` to your `i` element.

It should be the height of your surrounding parent element, in your case it is 40px.

```
.prev >i,
.next >i {
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tF4L5/3/)